# What do i need to communicate my sensors with LoRaWAN, simply?

Tags: sensor, rf, wireless, network

I'm new at wifi communications, i need to use Lora at my job project. I searched the internet to learn what the long range rf is. So, if i want to communicate with my sensors(on my mcu kits) over long distance(>10 km for example), are these enough?:

- mcu host with sensors
- lora modules for each node
- lora gateway

I read about base station requirements to use lora,does base station mean lora gateway? i have this figure:
http://www.rfwireless-world.com/images/LoRa-network.jpg
So i connect my mcus to lora modules, then it sends data to gateway at lora rf frenquencies. Is this true?

Comment: If you NEED to use Lora then you will have one or intend to have one. When you are able, do a test and see what happens.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm just researching before using it. But before taking a Lora, i wanted to figure out how it works. For example, i have 2 Lora modules( for my sensors from different places) and 1 gateway module. I read examples and understood them, to how to communicate them simple. But how does the gateway know we have 2 nodes? There is not a set up for that. What if another person around me uses lora modules? How can i seperate my nodes and his nodes?

Comment: Is there a pairing option between gateway and end-points(Lora nodes) like normal wireless devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base station means LoRa gateway.

Over 10 km would probably work but the modules have to be in line of sight. You can find range calculators on Libelium's site but it's better just to do the test.

Remember that using LoRa gateway means that you have to implement LoRaWAN network protocol. You have to handle resource-intensive code on yours mcus or buy modules with LoRaWAN already implemented like RN2483. If you don't have many sensors please concern using just peer-to-peer connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have too many sensors in different places in around the city, so I was wondering if I can handle the LoRaWAN implementation. As you said, I am considering using modules which have LoraWAN stack.

Comment: Could you please provide a link for the range calculator?

Comment: I can't find the one on Libelium website but here's another: https://www.link-labs.com/symphony

Answer (score 0):

Communication between two LoRa SX 1278 module using Arduino pro mini.Internet Of Things IoT Using Rf LoRa1278.
click to see
https://youtu.be/FpgbShufCB0